# how put predifined text in text box

Tags: vba, text, textbox

how do i put text in a text box that shows up on start i used the following but it dont work?

```
    TextBox1.Text = "enter your name here!"
```

the text box remains empty?

ta-

Comment: There are differences in the behaviour of textboxes between MS applications. It is usually best to say which application you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You must do the code on form_load. Set the text property to "enter your name here" as you already have.

```
TextBox1.Text = "enter your name here!"
```

Answer (score 1):

try `TextBox1.Value = "enter your name here!"`

Comment: Nope tryed that before but get the error Value is not a member of "system.windows.forms.textbox